# removing a marble

Tags: probability, combinatorics, logic, polya-counting-theory

A bag contains 3 red, 4 white, and 5 blue marbles. Jason begins removing marbles from the bag at random, one at a time. What is the maximum number of marbles he must remove to be sure that the bag consist at least 1 marble of each color?

What is the maximum number of marbles indicating to?

Comment: I need logic on this one. The options are: (a)1 (b)2 (c)4 (d)10 (e)12

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Well, since you have only a few options, you could just try them  all out. Option (a) would mean that, if you remove 1 marble, you'd still have at least one of each color in the bag but if you remove 2 then one color might have been completely removed. Option (b) would mean that, if you remove 2 marbles, you'd still have at least one of each color in the bag but if you remove 3 then one color might have been completely removed. And so on for the other options. Think about each option and see whether it's right or not.

Comment: well i need to understand what's the maximum number of marbles is indicating to. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: #Andreas Blass thanks a lot but that's not what i needed so i mentioned the options in  comment rather than in  the question body. And the question want to be certain ( TO BE SURE ) that the bag consist at least 1 marble of each color

Comment: If you couldn't answer at least you can up vote this question for helping me get the answer.

Comment: If you don't want to use the fact that there are only a few options, you could still try out the first few numbers to see what happens. In other words, try 1 and 2 as I suggested, and then, if you don't want to use that 3 isn't an option, try 3 also, and then 4. (The correct answer is small enough that you'll find it in less time than it took you to write the question and comments.)

Comment: "What is the maximum number of marbles indicating to".  In the paragraph above: "number of marbles he must remove to be sure that the bag consist at least 1 marble of each color".  So if you remove $2$, he can be sure he has at least one red, at least two whites, and at least three blues.  But if he removes $3$, he can be sure he has at least one white, and at least one blue, but he cant be sure he has any reds.  So the answer is $2$.

Comment: @fleablood you are a hero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This a puzzle/trick and not probability at all.

If he removes $3$ they *might* all red and he won't have $1$ of every color.

So the answer is $2$.  If he removes only $2$ he can't run out of any color and if removes $3$ he *might* run out of red.

And that's all this question asks.  Nothing more.

Comment: #fleablood you are the man. Thanks a lot dude that's what i was looking for ( the logic ). I am very much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

I would *slightly* rephrase the question.

> What is the maximum number of marbles he **may** remove **yet still** be sure that the bag consist at least 1 marble of each colour?

So consider: How many marbles must be removed to *become unsure* that there is still at least one marble of each colour?  (Without looking at the marbles removed.)  The answer you require is one less than that.

Comment: Thank you, but can you make me clear furthermore. sorry for the inconvenience